# python regular expression re.search(r"([a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+)", password)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

python 2.7

```
>>>import re
>>>password="ULFFunH8ni"
>>>re.search(r"([a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+)", password)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff5ffd075d0>
```

can match
but when

```
>>>password="Fa11con77YES"
>>>re.search(r"([a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+)", password)
>>>
```

can't match, I don't know why, can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now your regex checks for lower case characters immediately followed by upper case characters immediately followed by numbers.

Comment: I think you are confused between `re.search` and `re.match`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to ensure that the password has at least one of each (lower, upper, number) then you need to do separate checks:

```
low = re.search(r"[a-z]", password)
up = re.search(r"[A-Z]", password)
num = re.search(r"[0-9]", password)
has_all = all((low, up, num))
```

Basic regexes are order-specific. Another way of doing this would be to use lookaheads (if your regex flavor supports it):

```
re.search(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])")
```

However this may be less efficient than just doing each of the checks independently.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

`re.search(r"([a-z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]+)", password)`

it should match the order of the character as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression describes strings that have 1 or more lower case characters followed by 1 or more upper case characters followed by one or more digits.

In the first case (ULFFunH8ni) it finds "unH8";

In the second case (Fa11con77YES) there is no substring that matches.

If you want the entire string to match the regular expression you should use re.match();